# Implementing compression in asp.net mvc6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for ways to handle uploading large volume of data using mvc6 and Ajax. In mvc5 we used to set Json gzip compression. How to handle this correctly in mvc6 for both uploads and download of Json data?

Comment: Did your MVC5 approach stop working?

Comment: Response compression is an IIS feature, not an MVC or Ajax feature. *Request* compression though should be performed by the browser and I seriously doubt that any browser supports this.